How to process a GET request in TIdHTTPServer when changing the position of a video in the browser?
I'm trying to write a simple HTTP server that can send videos (mp4) to the browser. But I can't make it so that the user can randomly change the playback position of the video in the browser.
I'm able to send the video file in full and it plays in the browser. I do something like this in IdHTTPServer1CommandGet:
...
AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create('MyVideo.mp4', fmOpenRead or fmShareCompat);
...

But if I change the playback position in the browser, for example, jump 30 minutes ahead, then this does not work.
How to implement this feature? What code should be in the IdHTTPServer1CommandGet procedure? I couldn't find the answer on the Internet.

Have you tried to check (or log) what data is sent from the browser in the HTTP request when the position is changed?

Part of the problem is, that the server needs to move the position "in the file" 30 minutes ahead. This can not be done with TFileStream.

@mjn well, it CAN, but you'd have to calculate the correct byte position based on the video's encoding.

@Alex does the GET request include a Range header? If so, you can wrap the TFileStream inside of TIdHTTPRangeStream to deliver a portion of the file stream to the browser.  See Create video streaming server in indy
